# Create a VPN to get around blocked ports

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, ppp

I'm working on my laptop in a library at a university, where the "free" guest wifi blocks all ports except 22, 80, 443, and some others.

This prevents me from using some services like SMTP-TLS. However, I can still use SSH to connect to my home machine which has unrestricted Internet access.

What is the simplest way to set up a VPN that forwards traffic for the blocked ports through my home machine?

There is the [VPN PPP-SSH Mini-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/ppp-ssh/) which is pretty good, but stops short of assembling all the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I put together based on [Unix SE's "Output traffic on different interfaces based on destination port"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port), [the Netfilter HOWTO](https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html), and [iptables rule to submit packets matching a specific negative rule](https://serverfault.com/questions/151781/iptables-rule-to-submit-packets-matching-a-specific-negative-rule).

First add a new routing table to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
$ grep vpntab /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
200 vpntab
```

This script needs to be installed on the server that will be forwarding your packets:

```
$ cat =setup-vps-forwarding
#!/bin/zsh

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# this doesn't work
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Here is the main script to set up a VPN. The reason for SSH_VPSHOST to be a separate variable is in case your VPS host doesn't allow you to ssh as root, as in the below example where `sudo` is used, or if you want to ssh tunnel over multiple hosts. In the latter case, VPSHOST should be the numerical IP address of the first host in the chain.

```
$ cat simple-ppp-vpn
#!/bin/zsh
# EDIT ME
USER=myusername
VPSHOST=myhostname.net
PORT=22
SSH_VPSHOST="sudo -u $USER ssh -vTax $USER@$VPSHOST sudo"

# remember to put setup-vps-forwarding on $VPSHOST

# the IPs to use; just need that someone else isn't using them
REMPPP=192.168.3.2
LOCPPP=192.168.3.1
# try to infer the current default network interface
DEFIF=$(route -n | grep UG | head -n 1 | awk '{print $8}')

[[ "$UID" -eq 0 ]] || { >&2 echo "Need to be root"; exit 1 }

disable_rpfilt () {
    # disable rp_filter
    for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do
        echo 0 > $f;
    done
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
}

case $1 in
    restart)
        $0 stop; $0 start;;
    stop)
        killall pppd
        iptables -F OUTPUT
        iptables -F POSTROUTING
        iptables -t nat -F
        iptables -t mangle -F
        ip route flush table vpntab
        >&2 echo waiting for PPPD to die
        while pgrep pppd > /dev/null; do
            sleep 0.5;
        done
        ;;
    start)
        if pgrep pppd; then >&2 echo Another pppd is running; exit 1; fi
        set -x
        set -e

        disable_rpfilt

        # start pppd's on both ends
        pppd updetach defaultroute noauth passive pty "$SSH_VPSHOST pppd nodetach noauth notty" $LOCPPP:$REMPPP

        # enable NAT on $VPSHOST
        ssh $USER@$REMPPP sudo setup-vps-forwarding

        # set up route-based forwarding

        # add a new routing table 'vpntab', it must first exist in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
        grep vpntab /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
        # e.g. 200 vpntab

        # the new routing table sends stuff through the PPP device
        ip route add default via $REMPPP dev ppp0 table vpntab
        ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table vpntab

        ################################################################
        # allow ourselves to access the VPS host directly. change these two
        # commands if you want different traffic to be forwarded

        iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o $DEFIF -p tcp --dport $PORT -d $VPSHOST -j ACCEPT
        # this would be less specific
        # iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o $DEFIF -p tcp --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT

        # mark everything else for VPN routing
        iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o $DEFIF -j MARK --set-mark 1

        # replace the above two commands with this, to route only
        # one protocol through the VPN:
        # iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o $DEFIF -p tcp --dport 587 -j MARK --set-mark 1
        ################################################################

        # we need to rewrite the source address of routed packets.
        # this is a bit cleaner than duplicating the test as in
        # the Unix SE question
        iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp0 -m mark --mark 1 -j SNAT --to $LOCPPP

        ip route flush cache
        ;;
esac
```

I tried to make this as simple as possible but there are some things that I still don't understand. The linked questions describe some gatchas, for example having to disable rp_filter, and rewrite the source address with SNAT, which were both necessary.

I imagine that a better version of this would use socks or openvpn or `ssh -D`, rather than PPP.